# Time Datatype SQL Server 2008 and C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have one textbox (asp:textbox). I am using C#.NET and SQL Server 2008 R2 as the database. I've a problem when I'm trying to input the time. I.e. 08:00, 14:00, etc.
After I clicked Submit, it should be store to the table. But error. The error is "***String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan***". The fieldname is 'YourTime', datatype time(7).
I am using sqlcommand to store it to the table.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@YourTime", SqlDbType.Time, 7).Value = txtYourTime.Text;
```

Anyone can help for this?
Thank you so much.
Cheers,

Comment: Just to make sure there are no spaces, try `txtYourTime.Text.Trim()`.

Comment: Please refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx)

Comment: @Kaf, I did. Still the same.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, Give me an example please.. Based on my case. Cheers,

Comment: If your users are entering hours and minutes why are you passing 7 as the SQL type width? You are not going to be using all those fractional digits and wasting space (more memory to cache same rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach is to convert the text (string) value from `txtYourTime.Text` into a `TimeSpan` using [`TimeSpan.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992769.aspx).

Pass the [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) (for the [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) parameter) that reflect's your user (different cultures use different formats). This ensures you control these parameters rather than defaults which reflect the setup of the servers rather than the user's intent.

EDIT: Sample as requested:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Request.UserLanguages[0]);
TimeSpan ts;
if (TimeSpan.TryParse(txtYourTime.Text, ci, out ts)) {
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@YourTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = ts;
} else {
  // Report invalid input to user.
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example based on my question?

Comment: @Haminteu Done, you'll need to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your string into a valid `TimeSpan` like this:

```
myTime = TimeSpan.Parse(txtYourTime.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@YourTime", SqlDbType.Time, 7).Value = myTime;
```

Comment: Hi mate, i am using your code. but the error still the same. any idea?